# How do I alert a Windows 10 logged on user that another user has logged on?

Tags: python, powershell, system-administration

I would like to alert a logged in user on a sensitive Windows 10 machine when another account connects to the machine. How would you approach this problem? Is there a way to pull this off with Powershell or Python?

Comment: If you mean interactively on Windows. By design, only one use can be logged on to a system interactively at a time.

If you mean one user on the machine interactively and another via RDP or Remote connection, then for RDP, any RDP session, notify the RDP user that someone else is logged on and do you want to disconnect them (and they have to already be an authorized RDP user on the host). For remote connections, the user would have to manually send and invite and be on the system when that invite is used to accept the connection request.

What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Not interactively. A user is logged on and an administrator gets a shell on the system using psexec for example. How would I alert the interactive user that another session has started for another account?

Comment: I assumed you meant that or PoSH Remoting, but they are an admin in the enterprise and by that role, in most enterprises are allowed / required to do this because it's their job and the hosts are already configured to allow it. So, why would a normal user need to know about this action? Admins control what users do, not vice versa. Even if you did this another admin can turn it off via GPO - thus no logon, do what they need to an turn it back on. If you have rouge admins, that is a HR action / RPE producing event.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to turn on audit logging, advanced logging and PowerShell logging via GPO on the hosts and monitor for logon events via a Event Watcher - think WMI event consumer / aka event monitor, that fires a script to pop an alert to the user.

Monitoring Events
System administrators can use WMI to monitor events on a network. For example:

WMI supports event detection and delivery to event consumers because some WMI providers are event providers. For more information, see Receiving a WMI Event.

Event consumers are applications or scripts that request notification of events, and then perform tasks when specific events occur. You can create event monitoring scripts or applications that temporarily monitor when events occur. WMI also supplies a set of preinstalled permanent event providers and the permanent consumer classes that enable you to permanently monitor events. For more information, see Monitoring and Responding to Events with Standard Consumers.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392396(v=vs.85).aspx

There are many docs on what these are and hot to set them up. If you do a quick search, your uncover things, like the below.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/08/16/how-can-i-monitor-the-event-logs-for-the-occurrence-of-a-specific-event/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/20/use-powershell-to-create-a-permanent-wmi-event-to-launch-a-vbscript

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/19/using-the-wmi-admin-tools-to-check-on-permanent-events

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable logon auditing, then alert on the event log entry. The exact event id is specific to the version of Windows. Please refer to the following articles.

[Audit logon events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/auditing/basic-audit-logon-events)

[Track User Logon Session](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-user-logon-session-time-in-active-directory.html)